# Constraining constraints

Tags: haskell, ghc, constraint-kinds

I can write the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

f :: Integral a => (forall b. Num b => b) -> a
f = id
```

And all is good. Presumably GHC can derive `Integral` from `Num` so all is well.

I can be a bit tricker, yet I'm still fine:

```
class Integral x => MyIntegral x
instance Integral x => MyIntegral x

class Num x => MyNum x
instance Num x => MyNum x

f' :: MyIntegral a => (forall b. MyNum b => b) -> a
f' = id
```

So lets say I want to generalise this, like so:

```
g :: c2 a => (forall b. c1 b => b) -> a
g = id
```

Now obviously this will spit the dummy, because GHC can not derive `c2` from `c1`, as `c2` is not constrained.

What do I need to add to the type signature of `g` to say that "you can derive `c2` from `c1`"?

Comment: When you say "derive X from Y", I'd rather say "derive Y from X". In your first example, we have that `Integral t` implies `Num t`, and not the other way around. GHC has to extract a `Num` dictionary from the passed `Integral` one. And similarly for the other cases you mention below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`constraints`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package provides a solution to this problem, via its `:-` ("entails") type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Exts

data Dict :: Constraint -> * where
    Dict :: a => Dict a

newtype a :- b = Sub (a => Dict b)
infixr 9 :-

g, g' :: c2 a => c2 a :- c1 a -> (forall b. c1 b => b) -> a
g (Sub Dict) x = x
```

Then, by passing in an appropriate witness, we can recover the original example:

```
integralImpliesNum :: Integral a :- Num a
integralImpliesNum = Sub Dict

f :: Integral a => (forall b. Num b => b) -> a
f = g integralImpliesNum
```

In fact, this `g` is merely a flipped and specialized version of the `\\` operator:

```
(\\) :: a => (b => r) -> (a :- b) -> r
r \\ Sub Dict = r
infixl 1 \\

g' = flip (\\)
```

If you have the time, Edward Kmett's talk ["Type Classes vs the World"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZxTQP1ifo&t=2700s) is a great introduction to how this all works.